# Keyboard hides the screen

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using few inputs to submit data. When keyboard pops up, the ion-input fields get hidden and I cant see the input fields. From somewhere I read to set scrollEnabled true in config.xml file but that also doesn't solve issue. At the first launch of the application keyboard hides the input but from second launch keyboard doesn't hide input fields. How to solve this issue. Please help.